# Shell script spawning a process after a delay

Tags: bash, shell

How can I spawn a process after a delay in a shell script? I want a command to start 60 seconds after the script starts, but I want to keep running the rest of the script without waiting 60 seconds first. Here's the idea:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Echo A 60 seconds later, but without blocking the rest of the script
sleep 60 && echo "A"

echo "B"
echo "C"
```

The output should be

```
B
C
... 60 seconds later
A
```

I need to be able to do this all in one script. Ie. no creating a second script that is called from the first shell script.

Comment: it does. simple and easy. short and sweet

Answer (score 49, accepted):

& starts a background job, so

```
sleep 60 && echo "A" &
```

Comment: I was surprised to see that work without grouping (parentheses or braces).  Thanks :-)

Comment: It needs parens, like https://stackoverflow.com/a/1915082/377456. At least on zsh it does.

Answer (score 14):

Can't try it right now but

`(sleep 60 && echo "A")&`

should do the job

Answer (score 9):

A slight expansion on the other answers is to wait for the backgrounded commands at the end of the script.

```
#!/bin/sh
# Echo A 60 seconds later, but without blocking the rest of the script

set -e

sleep 60 && echo "A" &
pid=$!

echo "B"
echo "C"

wait $pid
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative:

```
echo 'echo "A"' | at now + 1 min
```

If somehow the OS is not running at the specified time, the command will be executed as soon as it is available.