# Linux folder permissions not inherited with symfony new project

Tags: linux, symfony, debian, file-permissions

I'm setting up a new web server, and getting some issues with folder perms when generating a new symfony project.

All my websites are located into `/var/www`
My symfony installer is located in `/usr/local/bin/symfony`
And this my my symfony installer ownership and perms:
`-rwxr-xr-x 1 root staff 233229 Oct 11 00:56 symfony`

Here is what I did on my website main folder :
`chown :www-data /var/www/`
`chmod g+s /var/www/`
`setfacl u:my-user:rwx,d:u:my-user:rwx,g:www-data:rwx,d:g:www-data:rwx /var/www`

When uploading file, everything is fine, group and perms are inherited correctly.

The problem is when I generate a new symfony project with the following command while located into `/var/www`:
`symfony new my_project`

This is the project folder perms:
`drwxr-xr-x 9 501 root 4096 Oct 15 00:20 test`

And the perms inside the project folder:
`drwxr-xr-x 4 501 staff 4096 Oct 15 00:20 app`
`drwxr-xr-x 2 501 staff 4096 Oct 15 00:20 bin`
`-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 2032 Oct 15 00:20 composer.json`
`-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 74614 Oct 15 00:20 composer.lock`
`-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 248 Oct 15 00:20 .gitignore`
`-rw-r--r-- 1 501 staff 978 Oct 3 21:12 phpunit.xml.dist`
`-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 68 Oct 15 00:20 README.md`
`drwxr-xr-x 3 501 staff 4096 Oct 15 00:20 src`
`drwxr-xr-x 3 501 staff 4096 Oct 15 00:20 tests`
`drwxr-xr-x 5 501 staff 4096 Oct 15 00:20 var`
`drwxr-xr-x 15 501 root 4096 Oct 15 00:20 vendor`
`drwxr-xr-x 3 501 staff 4096 Oct 3 21:14 web`

ACL aren't inherited at all. 
After a lookup, `501` seems to be the daemon user.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Looks wired with that `root staff` in it. Try `sudo chown staff.staff /usr/local/bin/symfony` then `sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/symfony` (or `sudo chmod +rx /usr/local/bin/symfony`. And also I think you need to change to ownership of you `/var/www/` directory, as `staff.staff` or I think once you'll install projects with symfony's command, the new created directories inside `/var/www/` will gain automatically the ownership applied through symfony. Not sure though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `recursive` Preciel.

Try:

```
setfacl -R ...
```

Also the commands you used sets the permission for `/var/www`, but nothing underneath that!

Comment: That would be if I wanted to set the ACL to existing sub folders. Here it's about inherit existing ACL & Group. Also, `chown g+s` is what make the group inherit to new sub folders and files. And last, just like I said, when I upload file, vie ftp or shh, group a perms are inherited just fine... The problem is somewhere else.

Comment: That is a dilemma. I see [from this post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182212/chmod-gs-command) that for files that are `moved` to the directory are unaffected by the setguid settings. Maybe one solution is to create your Symfony project in another folder and then copy them over. But that might not work for you...

Comment: Somehow got an idea... Is it possible to monitor the `/var/www` folder, and each time a new folder (not a file) is created, moved or copied, it apply perms after a few secs?!

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: Because I don't know how to do it I guess.. haha

Comment: I think you might need to repost a different question for that. But this might help you: [spawn process after a delay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915062/shell-script-spawning-a-process-after-a-delay) [check if directory exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59838/check-if-a-directory-exists-in-a-shell-script)  So, don't you think I've helped you a few times? Do I at least deserve a thumbs up?

Comment: Ahah... Well, the `setfack -R` should be a thumb down... :P But I will at least thumb up the comments... ;) Thanks for the posts, I will check them out